# Spring Injection - Interfaces and Classes

Tags: java, spring

I want to be able to call Interfaces in my class, but have spring instantiate them with the right implementation class behind the scenes.

I.e. Normally you can do:

```
IClass clz = new Class();
```

I want to have the line `IClass clz;` preferable in the middle of a method (or as one of the attributes if it can't be done), where clz is instantiated to the class I want by Spring.

The reason I'd like to do it this way is because I want to be able to be able to change which implementation I want to use simply by editing the context files.

Even better, would be knowing how to do the above with class contructors that expect parameters. i.e. `new Class(ar1, arg2);`

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you tried this and encountered some problem? or you just asking "are Spring support IoC?". I only see that you described pattern what Spring (and IoC/DI) are made for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your class implement BeanFactoryAware and then Spring will inject the bean factory in your class. If you then want to get an instance of a class implementing your interface you say something like:

```
beanFactory.getBean(IClass.class);
```

If there are multiple beans that implement the same interface you will have to resolve by name. To create a new object each time you ask this, set the bean scope of the bean you're asking for to "prototype".

Answer (score 0):

You can include code such as:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
IClass clz = (IClass) context.getBean("beanName");
```

Not saying this is better per se than Gerco's answer btw, just it's an option, depending what you want to do.

You can also implement the *ApplicationContextAware* interface: I've found that using ApplicationContext gives me beans with filled-in properties, e.g. if you have an *app.properties* file which contains key/value property pairs which you expect to be resolved within the Spring config, beans retrieved via BeanFactory calls may not resolve those.

See this [previous SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext) for more info.

Comment: As long as you create an ApplicationContext in your code, Spring will resolve the properties, placeholders, etc and pass you a reference to the ApplicationContext in setBeanFactory(). Every ApplicationContext is also a BeanFactory so BeanFactoryAware will work fine when all you need is getBean(). If you also want to access other methods that *are* application context specific, use ApplicationContextAware.

Comment: True but ApplicationContext is probably safer to use in general. I can never really remember the details to this - one of those things you work it out once then it all "just works" from that point.  Reading background about it again though I do notice that the Spring docs themselves  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory now advocate: use ApplicationContext rather than BeanFactory unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Is it possible to use propertyplaceholders, but pass the values needed at run time?

Comment: babyangel86 - pretty sure you can override them at runtime, yes. Remember Spring objects are still just objects - you can always call setXXX() methods after you retrieve them from your ApplicationContext. It probably does need to be a 2 step operation though: step 1 being get your object, step 2 being setting any new desired values.

Comment: Thanks guys. A combo of both ur solutions was what the dr ordered!