# Spring @Required annotation not working as expected

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to test out Spring Annotations to see how they work with some simple examples derived from the [Spring 3.0 Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) (in this case the "@Required" annotation specifically).

To start, I came up with a basic "Hello World" type example that doesn't use any annotations.  This works as expected (i.e. prints "Hello Spring 3.0~!").

I then added a `DAO` object field to the `Spring3HelloWorld` class.  My intention was to deliberately cause an exception to occur by annotating the setter for the `DAO` with `@Required` but then not setting it.  However, I get a null pointer exception (since `this.dao` is null) when I was expecting an exception based on not following the annotation "rules/requirements".

I thought I would have needed to set the `DAO` object before calling any method from `Spring3HelloWorld`, but apparently that's not the case.  I assume I'm misunderstanding how `@Required` works.

So basically how would I get the following to give me an error along the lines of "Hey you can't do that, you forgot to set DAO blah blah blah".

Spring3HelloWorldTest.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Spring3HelloWorldTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource     ("SpringHelloWorld.xml"));

        Spring3HelloWorld myBean = (Spring3HelloWorld) beanFactory.getBean("spring3HelloWorldBean");
        myBean.sayHello();        

    }
}
```

Spring3HelloWorld.java:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

public class Spring3HelloWorld {

    private DAO dao;

    @Required
    public void setDAO( DAO dao ){
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println( "Hello Spring 3.0~!" );

        //public field just for testing
        this.dao.word = "BANANA!!!";
    }
}
```

SpringHelloWorld.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="dao" class="src.DAO" ></bean>
    <bean id="spring3HelloWorldBean" class="src.Spring3HelloWorld" ></bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Use of @Required annotation in spring application is deprecated.
Refer to the official page - [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess is you won't get any of the advanced behaviour with Spring and annotations because you are using an `XmlBeanFactory` instead of the recommended `ApplicationContext`.

-- edit --

Yup - see this Stack Overflow [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext).

Comment: Ah I wasn't aware of that. Thanks, I'll definitely try with ApplicationContext instead.