# Read all beans of class in Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I need to read all beans of class `com.Foo`.
How I used to do it:

```
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource(file));
Map elements = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors((ListableBeanFactory) factory, com.Foo.class);
```

It turns out that `XmlBeanFactory` is now deprecated. How do I read all beans of a given class in Spring 3.1 ?

---

edit: the *new* factory has to be able to load bean definition XML from any file, classpath or filesystem. Until now I used the Spring `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` interface and it worked pretty well (it has many implementations, for any kind of file)

Comment: Duplicate/related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231371

Comment: ListableBeanFactory is not deprecated, it's implemented by each and every application context class. There's nothing wrong with `beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors`

Comment: but `XmlBeanFactory` is deprecated. And I cant find a class that takes a `Resourc` as a ctor param (it's not always from classpath)

Comment: try using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext instead. Resources are supported only by the application contexts not by the simple bean factories imho

Comment: Like I said - I read bean definitions from files not necessarily from the classpath

Comment: Sorry I misread your statement - try using `file:` prefix

Comment: You can also use GenericApplicationContext if you need to read the bean definitions from unusual places http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html

Comment: I've updated the question. Please write an answer so I can accept it (if it works ;-)

Comment: @Queequeg `file:` prefix didn't work?

Comment: You want me to use a `ClassPathXml...` with a regular file? It sounds like a hack

Comment: Yep, it seems that I'm wrong ))) I checked the source of ClassPathXml..

Comment: Gotcha - the correct class is `GenericXmlApplicationContext` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that takes `Resource` and resource locations as constructor argument is
[`GenericXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericXmlApplicationContext.html)

From javadoc:

> Convenient application context with built-in XML support. This is a
>   flexible alternative to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and
>   FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, to be configured via setters, with an
>   eventual refresh() call activating the context.

As for `beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors()` and `ListableBeanFactory` they are not deprecated.