# Spring ApplicationContext - Resource leak: 'context' is never closed

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

In a spring MVC application, I initialize a variable in one of the service classes using the following approach:

```
ApplicationContext context = 
         new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/userLibrary.xml");
service = context.getBean(UserLibrary.class);
```

The UserLibrary is a 3rd party utility which I am using in my application. The above code generates a warning for the 'context' variable. The warning is shown below:

```
Resource leak: 'context' is never closed
```

I don't understand the warning. As the application is a Spring MVC application, I can't really close/destroy the context as I refer to the service while the application is running. What exactly is the warning trying to tell me?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are creating another application context as opposed to creating the bean within the application context bootstrapped by Spring MVC

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184177/converting-or-integrating-a-standalone-spring-application-to-a-spring-mvc-app for an explanation as to why i had to create a new container.

Comment: When does this waning get shown: while you create the context?

Comment: I only saw it in Eclipse (underlined in Yellow). I just checked the logs for when i run the application but i don't see the warning.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Since the app context is a [`ResourceLoader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) (i.e. I/O operations) it consumes resources that need to be freed at some point. It is also an extension of `AbstractApplicationContext` which implements `Closable`. Thus, it's got a `close()` method and can be used in a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

```
try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/userLibrary.xml")) {
  service = context.getBean(UserLibrary.class);
}
```

Whether you actually need to create this context is a different question (you linked to it), I'm not gonna comment on that.

It's true that the context is closed implicitly when the application is stopped but that's not good enough. Eclipse is right, you need to take measures to close it manually for other cases in order to avoid classloader leaks.

Comment: I think the source of the problem is actually the fact that i am created a different context. Removing that additional context is probably a better option than trying to resolve the warning. Thanks.

Comment: Worthy of note: While the base `ApplicationContext` inteface does not provide the `close()` method, `ConfigurableApplicationContext` (which `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` implements) does and extends `Closeable` to boot, so you can use the Java 7 try-with-resource paradigm.

Comment: @kbolino. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Comment: @kbolino See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423980/how-to-close-a-spring-application-context

Comment: +1 to @kbolino's comment here, because I was declaring my variable as an `ApplicationContext` and scratching my head over why I was getting the warning when there didn't appear to be a close method available...

Comment: On wrapping it up, it closes my appcontext automatically and shutdowns the app on the server, which isn't what i would want as the app is now down, in such a case

Answer (score 40):

`close()` is not defined in `ApplicationContext` interface.

The only way to get rid of the warning safely is the following

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
try {
    [...]
} finally {
    ctx.close();
}
```

Or, in Java 7

```
try(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...)) {
    [...]
}
```

The basic difference is that since you instantiate the context explicitly (i.e. by use of `new`) you know the class you are instantiating, so you can define your variable accordingly.

If you were not instantiating the AppContext (i.e. using the one provided by Spring) then you couldn't close it.

Comment: Again and again the wrong try...finally is teached to others... The `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);` must be outside of the try-block. Then there is no need for the null check. If the constructor throws an exception then `ctx` is null and the `finally` block is not called (because the exception was thrown outside the try-block). If the constructor didn't throw an exception then the `try` block is entered and `ctx` can't be null, so there is no need then for a null-check.

Comment: This answer is bad, there is a real problem with your try finally block. just tested but not working at all.

Answer (score 15):

A simple cast solves the issue:

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) fac).close();
```

Answer (score 8):

As the Application context has an instance of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and the same has a close() method. I would simply CAST the appContext object and invoke the close() method as below.

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
//do some logic
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) appContext).close();
```

This will fix the Resource Leak warning.

Answer (score 4):

try this. you need to apply cast to close applicationcontext.

```
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = null;
      try {
         ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
            [...]
             } finally {
              if (ctx != null)
                  ((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx).close();       
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Even I had the exact same warning, all I did was declare `ApplicationContext` outside the main function as `private static` and ta-da, problem fixed.

```
public class MainApp {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        HelloWorld objA = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

        objA.setMessage("I'm object A");
        objA.getMessage();

        HelloWorld objB = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");
        objB.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the warning problem but not the real issue which is leaving the context open and causing a leak. You could do the same with a `@SupressWarnings` annotation, but still better to solve the root problem, don't you think?

Comment: Yeah you're right.. it was just a workaround for me at that moment.

Comment: This is not a good answer. since the real issue remain the same, i.e there is a resource leak, context is never closed.

Answer (score 2):

Downcast the context to ConfigurableApplicationContext.

```
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
```

Comment: `((ConfigurableApplicationContext)(context)).close();` may be this is the right answer

Comment: The answer from amit28 is correct. Why is the answer not useful ?

Answer (score 2):

Casting is the correct resolution for this issue.
I faced the same issue using the below line.
`ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);`

To resolve the warning just downcast the `ctx` object like below and then close it.
`((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) ctx).close();`

Answer (score 1):

```
Object obj = context.getBean("bean");
if(bean instanceof Bean) {
    Bean bean = (Bean) obj;
}
```

In my case leak disappears

Answer (score 1):

This worked out best for me.

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class Test {

     private static ApplicationContext con;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         con = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");

         Employee ob = (Employee) con.getBean("obj");
         System.out.println("Emp Id " + ob.getEmpno());
         System.out.println("Emp name " + ob.getEmpname());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext** then you can use

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

to close the resource leak problem.

If you are using the **AbstractApplicationContext** then you can cast this with close method.

```
((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();
```

It depends on the type of context using in the application.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

((ConfigurableApplicationContext)ctx).close();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think this answer the question?

Comment: ClassPathXMLApplicationContext super class implements ConfigurableApplicationContext which contains the close() method. We can typecast the context into ConfigurableApplicationContext to call the close() method, it frees the resources. Simply also we can do like ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)ctx).close();

Answer (score 0):

You make the context a static variable, which means that the context is available to all the static methods in the class, and not limited to the scope of the main method anymore. So the tool can't assume that it should be closed at the end of the method anymore, so it doesn't issue the warning anymore.

```
public class MainApp {
    private static ApplicationContext context;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          context = 
                 new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

          HelloWorld obj = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorld");

          obj.getMessage();

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, interface `ApplicationContext` doesn't have `close()` method, so I like to use class `AbstractApplicationContext` to use that `close` method explicitly and also here you can use your Spring Application configuration class using annotation instead of `XML` type.

```
AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAppConfig.class);
Foo foo = context.getBean(Foo.class);

//do some work with foo

context.close();
```

your `Resource leak: 'context' is never closed` warning is gone now.

Answer (score 0):

it has a simple solution just input the Core jar into the libraries, given at this link
[download the core jar files for spring][1]
[1]: https://static.javatpoint.com/src/sp/spcorejars.zip

Comment: Please check the Markdown docs and use the preview, your URL seems to have been truncated.

Answer (score 0):

for ApplicationContext you can't use close() method because this method doesn't define int it but instead you can use:`(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(context)).close()`

Answer (score -1):

The method close has been added to ConfigurableApplicationContext interface, so the best you can do to get access to it is:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "/app-context.xml");

// Use the context...

context.close();
```