# How to close a spring ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

After my application finishes I want to close the spring context.
The relevant code has an `ApplicationContext` reference but I couldn't find a `close` method.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Downcast your [`ApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) to [`ConfigurableApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html) which defines [`close()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#close()) method:

```
((ConfigurableApplicationContext)appCtx).close();
```

Comment: You can also cast to `AbstractApplicationContext`

Comment: @eeezyy - As `AbstractApplicationContext` is a class and `ConfigurableApplicationContext` is an interface implemented by that class, it is probably better to use the latter in most cases.

Comment: As `ConfigurableApplicationContext` now extends `Closable` ( don't know which version this change was made in, but the docs for 4.2.x show it while 3.0.x doesn't) a much shorter version is `((Closable)context).close();`.

Comment: There's also now an `AutoCloseable` implementation, which means that a try-with-resources can now be used, as long as you store your context in a variable where the `AutoCloseable` interface is visible, i.e. `try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ....) { /* your code goes here  */ } // context is closed when you leave the try block`

Comment: Where should I close the context? I have a listener application that constantly gets messages through onMessage() method of the MessageListener class. In what part should I close the application context to finally shutdown the executor?

Comment: What if the current ApplicationContext has a parent? Should I close the parent too ?

Answer (score 36):

You need to register a shutdown hook with the JVM as shown below:

```
((AbstractApplicationContext)appCtx).registerShutdownHook();
```

For more information see: [Spring Manual: 3.6.1.6 Shutting down the Spring IoC container gracefully in non-web applications](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown)

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't work for me in a test class, but using Avner Levy's answer at the end of main() does work.

Comment: @JReader - shutdown hooks aren't reliable in many circumstances, and are not run by most test frameworks (because usually the VM doesn't actually quit between running tests) or quite a few application frameworks.(e.g. servlets -- anything that can terminate and reload an application without terminating the virtual machine, basically).  You probably shouldn't use them unless you know what you're doing and how your code would be used..

Answer (score 15):

If you initialise context like one below

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(beansXML);
```

clean context like these

```
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

Answer (score 15):

**If Java SE 7 and later**, don't close, use  try-with-resources which ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

```
try(final AbstractApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.xml" }))
{
     //write your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to close the `ApplicationContext` Object

1. Type Cast the `ApplicationContext` Object to `ConfigurableApplicationContext` object.
2. then call the close object on that.

example:

```
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mybeans.xml");

((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context ).close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringCnf.xml");
    Resturant rstro1=(Resturant)context.getBean("resturantBean");
    rstro1.setWelcome("hello user");
    rstro1.welcomeNote();
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
```

Comment: When answering an old post, it would be helpful if you could provide some context to your answer rather than just code, as it might make it more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Even a more simpler way of doing this is using the abstract implementation of the `ApplicationContextinterface`.

```
 AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

context.close();
```