# Why doesn't Spring call registerShutdownHook itself?

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I looked at several related questions (e.g., [How correctly close the ApplicationContext in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169916/how-correctly-close-the-applicationcontext-in-spring) and [How to close a spring ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423980/how-to-close-a-spring-applicationcontext?rq=1), and the Spring docs at [Shutting down the Spring IoC container gracefully in non-web applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-shutdown), and other sources) but didn't learn:

Why doesn't Spring itself call `AbstractApplicationContext::registerShutdownHook`?

Why is it left for the programmer to do?

I know it is not necessary to call it for web apps running in a container, only for standalone apps.  But the event happens so late in the JVM lifecycle that surely Spring could manage for itself whether or not the call was necessary, web app or not.  And it seems like an easy thing for the programmer to forget to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it left for the programmer to do?

You would need to discuss that design decision with the Spring designers!

However, here are some plausible reasons:

- Because the programmer may not want it to be done!
- Because a "one size fits all" shutdown hook may be inappropriate.
- Because when there are multiple shutdown hooks registered, the
  javadocs state that the order of initialization is unspecified. 
  (Meaning that if Spring did register a hook, that hook could
  interfere with what the programmer needs to do in another hook.)