# Spring ApplicationContext.close() doesnot shut down application

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to shut down my application ( which is a jar and is run manually)

I have read this : http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/98741-how-to-applicationcontext-memory-leaks-in-spring-3-0-x

[Spring ApplicationContext - Resource leak: 'context' is never closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184059/spring-applicationcontext-resource-leak-context-is-never-closed/14830121)

and as i am using the spring 3.2.18

my code looks like

```
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext parentContext ;
    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext processContext ;
    private final String  processApplicationContextChild; // filename: childContext.xml

    public void run() {

        log.debug("Loading parent context");

            parentContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml") ;
            parentContext.registerShutdownHook();

            try {
                runProcess(parentContext);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error("Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage(), e);


            } finally {
                log.info("Closing Core Context ");
                if (parentContext.isActive()){
                    parentContext.close();

                }
                log.info("Core Closed");

            }


    }

    protected void runProcess(ConfigurableApplicationContext parentContext) {
        log.info("Loading " + Arrays.asList(processApplicationContextChild));
         processContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(processApplicationContextChild, parentContext);
        processContext.registerShutdownHook();
        Runnable processor = (Runnable) processContext.getBean("processorRunnable", Runnable.class);

        try {
            processor.run();
        } finally {
            log.info("Closing child  Context ");
            processContext.close();
            log.info(" Child Closed");
        }
    }
```

After the "Core Closed" is printed out. it just hangs and does nothing. I am expecting the JVM to exit.

There is some resource some where either the child or parent which is not closed properly. how can i view that resource. Or what could be the issue here. 
when i debug, on each .close() call, the context is still an instance with closed=true and isActive=false.

I even made them non static and used a try with resource block.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a resource leak the solution of which is described here 
[RestEasyClient JAX RS possible resource leak if not done correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831789/resteasyclient-jax-rs-possible-resource-leak-if-not-done-correctly)