# Fix XmlBeanFactory Deprecated error Spring

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, deprecated

These days I'm learning Spring Framework. And I'm following some youtube videos.
According to the video I wrote my first code in Spring as same as the tutorial. But at a point I'm getting XmlBeanFactory deprecated warning which are not shown in tutorial.

I'm having two classes on MyPackage package.

```
package MyPackage;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;

public class DrawingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("Spring.xml"));
    Triangle triangle =(Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");

    triangle.draw();
}

}
```

Here my XmlBeanFactory is deprecated. I checked everywhere couldn't fix it

This is my Triangle class.

```
package MyPackage;

public class Triangle {

public void draw(){
    System.out.println("Draw a Triangle");
}
}
```

And this is my xml file "spring.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans>
<bean id="triangle" class="MyPackage.Triangle"></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Check this thread which may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231371/springs-xmlbeanfactory-is-deprecated

Comment: Thanks alot . it worked

Answer (score 2):

As XmlBeanFact was deprecated you can use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext factory = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle trianle=(Triangle)factory.getBean("triangle");
    trianle.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a XmlBeanFactory is deprecated you can use following code snippet.

```
public class SpringHelloWorldTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
           Triangle triangle =(Triangle) factory.getBean("triangle");
           triangle.draw();
}
```

}

Note : make sure to add "spring.xml" in build path.

Answer (score 0):

As `XmlBeanFactory` was deprecated you can use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        Triangle trianle=(Triangle)context.getBean("triangle");
        trianle.draw();

    }
```

Comment: As XmlBeanFactory was deprecated you can use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Answer (score 0):

Since the XmlBeanFactory is deprecated, as an alternate you can use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. ApplicationContext is a sub-interface of BeanFactory. Also, make sure that spring.xml is in the classpath (Under src folder).

```
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    // ApplicationContext appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) appContext.getBean("triangle");
    triangle.draw();
```

For more explanation, you can check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory