# Spring @Autowired constructor gives No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring, autowired, default-constructor

Some strange behavior from Spring 3.0 here.

```
package com.service.schedule;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("outroJob")
public class OutroJob {

    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("running...");
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.service.schedule;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("testeAutowired")
public class TesteAutowired {

    @Autowired
    public TesteAutowired(OutroJob outroJob) {
        outroJob.printMe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        XmlBeanFactory ctx = new XmlBeanFactory(res);

        OutroJob outroJob = (OutroJob) ctx.getBean("outroJob");
        outroJob.printMe(); // gives: running...

        ctx.getBean("testeAutowired");
    }
}
```

None of these beans are declared on applicationContext.xml

So, line outroJob.printMe(); works fine... prints "running..."

But when I try to get the "testeAutowired" bean, it says:

> Could not instantiate bean class
>   [com.service.schedule.TesteAutowired]: No default constructor found;
>   nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.service.schedule.TesteAutowired.

The question is: why, if Spring found the "outroJob" bean it doesn't autowired it on the TesteAutowired constructor ?

It seems obvious what it has to do...

Comment: What happens if you use ApplicationContext instead of XmlBeanFactory? I see XmlBeanFactory is deprecated in 3.1, maybe that's one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ApplicationContext instead of XmlBeanFactory. XmlBeanFactory doesn't postprocess annotations ie doesn't use AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor which would explain the behaviour you're experiencing.

[Here's some more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
@Autowired(required=true)
public TesteAutowired(OutroJob outroJob) {
    outroJob.printMe();
}
```

That should force Spring to use that constructor.  Otherwise it builds a list of constructors and picks the best candidate.  Apparently it really wants a default constructor as a candidate, I guess.

Reference: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html

Comment: I can't imagine how this could ever help when the default value for `required` is `true`. I.e. `@Autowired` == `@Autowired(required=true)`

Answer (score 0):

Create an inteface for the component and try to autowire the interface and nore the class with the autowired contructor.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error message but have different problem. I was using XML configuration and put `@Autowired` on class constructor.

I fixed this problem by enabling annotation driven config in my XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config/>
```