# Query Regarding application context and beanfactory in spring

Tags: java, spring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New to Spring - BeanFactory vs ApplicationContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext)

Why we always use the term "spring applicationcontext" when we talk about the spring application deployed in some app server. Why not bean factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the concrete implementation used by the app is also an instance of `ApplicationContext`, which extends `BeanFactory`.

Comment: then why there is lot of discussion about bean factory and applicationcontext.(which one to use and which one not to use) I am new to spring so pardon me if I asked something wrong

Comment: If you're new to Spring, read its documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans