# What is Application context and bean factory in spring framework

Tags: java, spring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BeanFactory vs ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext)

Simple word meaning of Application context and bean factory in spring framework.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**BeanFactory**

The `BeanFactory` is the actual container which instantiates, configures, and manages a number of beans. These beans typically collaborate with one another, and thus have dependencies between themselves. These dependencies are reflected in the configuration data used by the `BeanFactory` (although some dependencies may not be visible as configuration data, but rather be a function of programmatic interactions between beans at runtime).

**ApplicationContext**

While the beans package provides basic functionality for managing and manipulating beans, often in a programmatic way, the context package adds `ApplicationContext`, which enhances `BeanFactory` functionality in a more framework-oriented style. Many users will use `ApplicationContext` in a completely declarative fashion, not even having to create it manually, but instead relying on support classes such as `ContextLoader` to automatically start an ApplicationContext as part of the normal startup process of a Java EE web-app. Of course, it is still possible to programmatically create an ApplicationContext.

The basis for the context package is the `ApplicationContext` interface, located in the `org.springframework.context` package. Deriving from the `BeanFactory` interface, it provides all the functionality of `BeanFactory`. To allow working in a more framework-oriented fashion, using layering and hierarchical contexts, the context package also provides the following:

- MessageSource, providing access to messages in, i18n-style
- Access to resources, such as URLs and files
- Event propagation to beans implementing the ApplicationListener interface
- Loading of multiple (hierarchical) contexts, allowing each to be focused on one  particular layer, for example the web layer of an application

As the `ApplicationContext` includes all functionality of the `BeanFactory`, it is generally recommended that it be used over the `BeanFactory`, except for a few limited situations such as perhaps in an applet, where memory consumption might be critical, and a few extra kilobytes might make a difference. The following sections described functionality which `ApplicationContext` adds to basic `BeanFactory` capabilities.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html

Comment: Hi, I am reading a Spring 4 book. It mentions ApplicationContext. I know its an interface. But, what is this ApplicationContext really and what purpose does it serve (in plain english please) ? Why is the word application used ? Why not use SpringContext or UserContext ?

Comment: @Borat Sagdiyev  http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1245203&seqNum=3 i hope this will help you.

Comment: this is by far the most simple and best explanation i have found through  - https://dzone.com/articles/difference-between-beanfactory-and-applicationcont