# Difference between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, ioc-container

Both are actually ioc containers. But what is the actual difference between them? Which one is better to use?

Comment: this question is repeated with [question 243385](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApplicationContext is derived from BeanFactory to provide added functionality to work in web application.

You can instantiate your spring container by just writing

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
```

or

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext{"spring_dao.xml","spring_service.xml};
```

You can use one or more xml file depending on your project requirement. As I am here using two xml files i.e. one for configuration details for service classes other for dao classes. Here ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is child of ApplicationContext.

For better understanding the difference your can check the http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory site.

Choosing between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext  is also depends how you want load your beans.

ApplicationContext is preferred unless you need to save resources, like on a mobile application.

Answer (score 1):

Both BeanFactory and Application are used to manage life cycle of beans, ApplicationContext can do all things that a BeanFactory does along with AOP,Event etc..

Unless until resources are crucial, go for ApplicationContext.