# Spring automatic registration meaning

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

Whenever someone describes the difference between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext, an argument, "Automatic registration of BeanPostProcessor", is very common in favour of ApplicationContext interface. Unfortunately, I don't understand these magic words. Can someone elaborate, what does "automatic registration" mean here?

Many thanks!

> [BeanFactory vs ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/new-to-spring-beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext)
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory

Comment: Can you link your source?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please see the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't actually care unless you have a very specific use case. In certain environments, you may want to turn off some additional features that `ApplicationContext` has over `BeanFactory`. These are summarized [in this table](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory)

As for "Automatic registration of BeanPostProcessor", the `ApplicationContext` will detect beans that implement `BeanPostProcessor` and will use them to enrich the context while it is loaded. This is a very powerful feature of Spring, check [Container extension points](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension)