# How to create multiple IoC container instances in web application

Tags: java, spring

**How can I create and get multiple IoC container instances in web application?**

And in web application, there are 2 types of Spring containers - one is application context `ApplicationContext` and another is `WebApplicationContext`, I know I could have multiple `WebApplicationContext` if I declare multiple servlets using `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`, so suppose I have 3 such `DispatcherServlet` configuration and then one is global one (using `context-param`), **so does it mean that it would have 4 IoC containers?**

**And how can I get the object of those IoC container?**

I have read lot of SO questions related to application context but it is driving me crazy, things are clear for application context created using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` but in case of web i.e. `ApplicationContext` and `WebApplicationContext`, things are not at clear.

Please note that I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862681/java-spring-mutliple-applicationcontext) but it is for `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, but my all confusion is for application context w.r.t. to web applications.

*P.S.: There is really not any purpose for why I want to do this, I am in learning phase so I am trying to understand containers.*

Comment: What is your purpose for wanting multiple containers? This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @chrylis There is really not any purpose, I want am in learning phase so I am trying  to understand containers.

Comment: Then the answer is "yes, but it's extremely complicated, and it's not worth doing because I've never even heard of a situation where it's relevant"--and that was before the trend toward microservices. Note that Spring applications don't have *both* an `ApplicationContext` and a `WebApplicationContext`, `WebApplicationContext extends ApplicationContext`.

Comment: @chrylis See, this is where things are driving me crazy, check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files, as per this I can create both application context and web application context, especially check out the last answer.

Comment: That's some custom library that I've never seen, and I've never seen the pattern used. Especially now that Spring 5 is nearly out, and Spring Boot with JavaConfig is the de facto standard for application setup, nearly all of that is obsolete.