# What is the difference between BeanFactory container, ApplicationContext container and IOC container?

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring, I read **BeanFactory** is also called **basic IOC** and **ApplicationContext** is called **Advanced IOC**.

I read:

**BeanFactory Container** is the simplest container providing the basic support for DI and is defined by the org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory interface. The BeanFactory and related interfaces, such as BeanFactoryAware, InitializingBean, DisposableBean, are still present in Spring for the purpose of backward compatibility with a large number of third-party frameworks that integrate with Spring.

**ApplicationContext container** adds more enterprise-specific functionality such as the ability to resolve textual messages from a properties file and the ability to publish application events to interested event listeners. This container is defined by the org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext interface.

I am little bit confused::

> BeanFactory is **Basic IOC container** or **BeanFactory container**?
>
> ApplicationContext is **Advanced IOC container** or **ApplicationContext container**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeanFactory vs ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext)

Comment: I am asking difference between IOC container and BeanFactory container   AND IOC container and ApplicationContext container  NOT Beanfactory and Applicationcontext

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans

Comment: It means BeanFactory and ApplicationContext is IOC container. Then can you tell me what is BeanFactory container and Application container?

Comment: you can read the dupe for the difference between those..

Comment: If IOC container is there then what is the need of BeanFactory container?

Answer (score 0):

**The BeanFactory interface**

The root *interface* for accessing the Spring container. Spring’s Dependency Injection functionality using this BeanFactory interface and its subinterfaces.

**Features**:

- Bean instantiation/wiring

Important to mention that it only supports XML-based bean configuration.
Usually, the implementations use lazy loading, which means that Beans are only instantiating when we directly calling them through the getBean() method.

The most used API which implements BeanFactory is the XmlBeanFactory.

**The ApplicationContext interface**

The **ApplicationContext** is the central interface within a Spring application for providing configuration information to the application.

It implements the **BeanFactory** interface. Hence ApplicationContext includes all functionality of the BeanFactory and much more!
Its main function is to support the creation of big business applications.

**Features**:

- Bean instantiation/wiring
- Automatic BeanPostProcessor registration
- Automatic BeanFactoryPostProcessor registration Convenient
- MessageSource access (for i18n)
- ApplicationEvent publication

Supports both XML and annotation based bean configuration
Uses eager loading, so every bean instantiate after the ApplicationContext started up.

For more, see my blog post:

[Difference between BeanFactory and ApplicationContext in Spring – The java spring blog from the basics](https://www.zoltanraffai.com/blog/difference-between-beanfactory-and-applicationcontext/)

Answer (score 0):

BeanFactory: is Lezy instantiation of a bean because After creating IOC Container and after calling factory.getbean method then  BeanFactory request to IOC container for creating object of a bean.

ApplicationContext:is Eager instantiation of a bean It creates the object of a bean at the time creating IOC container.

BeanFactory:It does not support I18

ApplicationContext:It support.