# ApplicationContext not able to parse xml file getting Exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Please help me with to load and parse my spring.xml file using ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml")**

**file structure is given in images [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMHPL.png)**

[image: file and structure]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> should be the first line, then everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring-Context requires Spring-expression and Spring-AOP as compile dependency. you can check required dependencies here.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/5.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: @KailashChoudhary I cant find spring-expression and spring-aop in the attached image. Maybe attached image is outdated.

Comment: Is it mandatory for ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ? because it work fine for Resource r = new  ClassPathResource("resources/spring.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);

Comment: Thanks @lucid now its woking , but i want to know why XmlBeanFactory  working here

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243385/beanfactory-vs-applicationcontext